# Mathematica 7 and ODBC problems on Windows OS 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc, odbc, wolfram-mathematica

I'm setting up a replacement server. Mostly it runs Mathematica jobs. I set up the ODBC connections on the new box to be the same as on the old box, but when Mathematica tries to connect, using

```
testConn=OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["odbc","MyODBCName"]]
```

I get

```
JDBC::error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length
```

Searching on this mostly finds other people with related problems. Some references to 32/64 bit Java issues. I have Java 1.6.0_24 (32 bit) on the new server, 1.6.0 on the old. And Wolfram has not responded yet. Some programs that don't use ODBC to connect work fine on the new box.

Software versions are Mathematica 7, MS SQLServer 2008 on both boxes, Windows Server 2008 on the new one and Server 2003 on the old one. I created ODBC connections using both the 32 and 64 bit versions of odbcad32.exe

What am I missing, what didn't I tell you and what do you suggest?
Thanks, **kent

Comment: karchie, welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: We (as WReach suggested, but I didn't see until today) switched to the jTDS JDBC driver. This worked fine except for authentication. We had to get the ntlmauth.dll from the jTDS installation package to get this to work (stuck it in C:\WINDOWS\system32, be careful about 32/64 bit versions) . Wolfram didn't include that. So happy ending.

Answer (score 0):

Some people have had success by installing the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c06b8369-60dd-4b64-a44b-84b371ede16d).  Even though this update says "Access" in the title, it might be relevant to your problem because it also updates the ODBC framework itself.

Comment: Thanks, I talked to our IT and DB people and we decided to not try this for fear of breaking something else. We are going to change the code to use a different DB access library we have and skip around ODBC, so I will be no help to others reading this.

Comment: @karchie FYI, I have had great success accessing SQL Server from Java and Mathematica using the [jTDS JDBC Driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/).